# Why react doesn't show Image from url local

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, react-native, localhost, paperclip

hello every one I have an application running locally with RoR everything works fine in the backend, also I can see the Json in Postman

> http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/v1/articles

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "title": "Barack Obama",
        "description": "Sabias que? el era muy pobre",
        "avatar_content_type": "/system/articles/avatars/000/000/001/original/user-two.png?1509755893"
    }
]
```

and also in my mobile emulator I can see the Title and description that's mean everything works fine. BUT I can't see the image :/ some advice?

### ProductList.js

```
// step 1: import libraries
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { ScrollView } from 'react-native';
import Product from './Product';

export default class ProductList extends Component {

  state = {
    products: []
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    return fetch('http://MYIP:3000/api/v1/articles')
                .then((response) => response.json())
                .then((responseJson) => {
                  this.setState({products: responseJson})
                })
  }

  render() {

    var productList = this.state.products.map(function(item) {
      return (
        <Product title = { item.title }
                 description = { item.description }
                 image_url = { item.avatar_content_type }
                 key = { item.id }/>
      )
    })
    return (
      <ScrollView>
        { productList }
      </ScrollView>
    );
  }
}
```

### Product.js

```
// step 1: import libraries
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Alert, Image } from 'react-native';

// step 2: create component
export default class Product extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Image source={{uri: this.props.image_url }} style={{width: 60,height: 60,}}/>
        <Text style = { style.textStyle }>{ this.props.title }</Text>
        <Text style = { style.textStyle }>{ this.props.description }</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const style = StyleSheet.create({
  textStyle: {
    fontSize: 20,
    padding: 20
  },
  amountStyle: {
    fontSize: 15,
    paddingLeft: 20
  }
})
```

> I dont get exceptions or something similar, I'm not just be able to see the Image in my mobile emulator

Comment: Mobile app doesn't understand where to look for `/system/articles/avatars/000/000/001/original/user-two.png?1509755893` you need to give it full http eg. http://192.168.1.103/system/articles/avatars/000/000/001/original/user-two.png?1509755893

Comment: thanks :)! it works

Answer (score 0):

It may be because It is empty during the first render as you are trying to perform an asynchronous operation 
So what you could do is u can check by giving a condition I normally do it with lodash using _.isEmpty method

try this:

```js
<Image source={{uri: (_.isEmpty(this.props.image_url) ? null : this.props.image_url) }}
```